# How to load Ubuntu boot option after hiding it in Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I've installed Ubuntu, and I had it set so that whenever I turned on my laptop, it would load a purple screen that would allow me to pick from Ubuntu or Windows. Well, I screwed with a setting in Windows and now it doesn't give me the boot option to load Ubuntu's purple load menu. How do I get this back?

Comment: Can you please elaborate.What exactly did you do in Windows?

Comment: I want to say I went into the boot options of windows to load something, but I rerverted it back to the original settings I had set for Ubuntu and it still doesn't load.

Comment: So you're saying you can't access Ubuntu at all? You might find some help [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

I guess "purple load menu" refers to the Ubuntu GRUB2 boot menu.

You can run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) again to fix this problem.

Boot-Repair is a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues you may encounter in Ubuntu like when you can't boot Ubuntu after installing Windows or another Linux distribution, or when you can't boot Windows after installing Ubuntu, or when GRUB is not displayed anymore, some upgrade breaks GRUB, etc.

Boot-Repair lets you fix these issues with a simple click, which (generally reinstalls GRUB and) restores access to the operating systems you had installed before the issue.

If you can boot into Ubuntu which is installed into your disk, use it. Else, get a USB stick or a disc with Ubuntu inside and in the menu, choose `Try Ubuntu Without Installing`.

In your Ubuntu(make sure that you're connected to Internet), open `Terminal`.

Now type these commands.(Copy > Paste > Enter line by line)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

After a while, you should see a this.

[image]

Click `Recommended repair` button. Follow the instructions(It will ask you to copy&paste some commands). You should note the URL(paste.ubuntu.com/whatever). Now reboot your computer, you should see Ubuntu, Windows 8 and other options in a purple UI. Use arrow keys to move the highlightned line and press enter. If you didn't see it, that means the repair didn't success. Paste the URL you've noted bolow.